# Set interval over each() loop work for first element only

Tags: jquery, dom, setinterval

I am trying to set time interval fro each element of particular group elements on my web page. It works only for first element in the row.
So the input are id = "item-info-8"  which later fetches 8 from it and assign to vid variable. Expire date - simple text from buffer tag to use it from DB (11/11/2012 20:20:10).
So I was googling about that, trying to use array to assign each object of that method, nothing worked. First countdown is correct, rest are undefined.

```
var Adds=new Array();
var im=0;
$( ".tender-panel" ).each(function() {
          var id=$(this).find('.well').attr('id'); 
          var expire=$(this).find('.expire').text();
            var vid=id.substr(9); 
            Adds[im++]=MyInterval(id,vid,expire);
        });
    });

function MyInterval(id,vid,expire){
    setInterval(function(){
        console.log(expire);
        var time=TenderCount(expire);
        console.log(time);
        if(time!=undefined){
        $("#"+id).find('.tender-status').text("Tender finish in "+time.days+" days "+time.hours+":"+time.minutes+":"+time.seconds);

        }else{
            $("#"+id).find('.tender-status').text("Tender Closed");
            $('#'+id).find('.bet').addClass('disabled');

            for(var i=0;i<TendersData.length;i++){

                if(TendersData[i].vid==vid && TendersData!=null){
                    console.log(TendersData);
                }
            }
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: MyInterval is not returning anything. So, the array `Adds` does not contain any value.

Comment: If you can create a jsFiddle that demonstrates the issue, it is easy for someone to answer